# d3: draw heat map by US individual state

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using this GeoJSON `http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_5m.json`. Since it gives data about US counties, when I draw the path, the US is divided into counties. However, is there a way to only draw path by states? Then, when a user clicks on a state, the map will zoom in and show the heat map of that state.

This is what I wrote to draw path:

```
d3.json("http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_5m.json", function(data) {

    svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", "1");
    .style("fill", "orange");

});
```

I would really appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Something like [this](http://techslides.com/demos/d3/us-zoom-county.html)?  Note that example is using JSON that contains paths for counties and states.

Comment: @Mark Thanks a lot! It's useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the geojson you have is divided by counties, the easy way to fix this is looking for a geojson of the states, in any case here is a link that may help you. And also contains a geojson of the states.
[GeoMapping in D3](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch12.html)